# Index Match Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to lookup a value based on row and column header. It will be based on cells `A1` and `A2`.
The table array area is `D:F`.

The reason i need vlookup/index match is because the row and column header may change places.

I am expecting value of 10 in the yellow highlighted cell.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question title hints at, use `INDEX/MATCH/MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(D:F,MATCH(A2,D:D,0),MATCH(A1,D1:F1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be retrieving values but they are incorrect (my workbook is alot bigger I just used a sample).  So the index part should be the full sheet selected? First match should be the row lookup with only the column with the rows Im looking for. And Second Match should be column lookup with only the column headers selected. I

Comment: You are spot on - first match should be the row lookup, second match should be the column lookup. Maybe use Formulas > Evaluate Formula to determine the result of each MATCH to verify it's what you expect.

Comment: When I evaluate formula, the row  is incorrect. It is way off, It should be returning row 62 but instead returning row 32. Weird.

Comment: What is the first match formula you used? Did you use full column references (e.g. D:D)?

Comment: `=INDEX(CM!B:AY,MATCH(A8,CM!B5:B70),MATCH(C4,CM!P3:AY3))`   . CM is the sheet I want to return values from. B to AY is where all values are stored.

Comment: `=INDEX(CM!B3:AY70,MATCH(A8,CM!B3:B70),MATCH(C4,CM!B3:AY3))`.

Comment: Sweet the row is correct but i forgot to tell you, the column is wrong too. it is returning the last column (col 50) ,  should be returning column 18

Comment: `=INDEX(CM!B3:AY70,MATCH(A8,CM!B3:B70,0),MATCH(C4,CM!B3:AY3,0))`